# How to test a chat script with a uucp linux and uucp(server) unix?

Tags: unix, linux

I like to play with old networks, uucp is really and advanced(is from the 1978) for that time.
I have setup a uucp server in a tru64 unix server.
On tru64 server
I have edit `/etc/inetd.conf`

```
uucp    stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/sbin/uucpd         uucpd
```

Then I create the nuucp user for login from remote machines

```
useradd -d /var/spool/uucppublic -s /usr/lib/uucp/uucico
```

The I have edit the Systems file

```
linux.my.site Any TCP,t - - in:--in: nuucp word: mypass
tru64-1.my.site Any TCP,t - - in:--in: nuucp word: mypass
```

Then edit the Permission file

```
MACHINE=slack64.my.site REQUEST=yes READ=/var/spool/uucppublic WRITE=/var/spool/uucppublic  COMMANDS=rmail:uucp
LOGNAME=nuucp REQUEST=yes SENDFILES=yes READ=/var/spool/uucppublic WRITE=/var/spool/uucppublic
```

And after restart inetd

```
kill `ps -e -o pid,comm |grep inetd|grep -v grep|head -1|awk '{print $1}'`
inetd
```

I have test from tru64 server the uucp..and works

```
/usr/lib/uucp/uucico -r1 -x9 -stru64-1.my.site
```

Now the configuration on linux side

I have edit the file /etc/uucp/sys

```
system tru64-1.my.site
address tru64-1.my.site
time any
call-login *
call-password *
chat ogin: \L\n\c word: \P
port TCP
protocol t
```

the file /etc/uucp/port

```
port            TCP
type            tcp
service         uucp
```

and the file 
/etc/uucp/call

```
tru64-1.my.site nuucp mypass
```

And..nothing work.
I have tried to debug with uucico, but I cannot see the "full procedure" even if I enable the debug,uucico exit silent!

```
uucico -f --debug 9 -x9 -stru64-1.my.site
```

uulog said

```
uucp tru64-1.my.site (10/18-3:13:31,31103,0) Calling system tru64-1.my.site (port TCP)
uucp tru64-1.my.site (10/18-3:13:32,31103,0) ERROR: Line disconnected
```

I think the error is in the chat script but not sure, probably bad configuration of uucp via tcp.

Comment: I almost hit 'close' as well, as this question is, like most practical unix questions borderline, but lets be honest, UUCP on a true64 installation isn't exactly today's stuff - even with definitive off topic Linux involved. So I'd give it the benefit of an (mostly) classic environment: Leave Open.

Comment: https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1328 ?

Comment: I had to dig up my .sig file from almost 30 years ago which had the quote `Like many of the features of UNIX, UUCP appears theoretically unworkable... - DEC Professional, April 1990`. I'm not sure I would agree with @Raffzahn that this is a practical Unix question.

Comment: @doneal24 When theoretical unworkable, it mut be a practical issue, isn't it? :)) SCNR

Comment: @Raffzahn `uucp` on any platform is obsolete. It definitely counts as retro IMO.

Comment: @elbarna On your True64 system, can you check that `inetd` is listening on your external interface, not just loopback.

Comment: Is listening on external interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my vague recollections there was one configuration file that tied all the loose ends - that is, when a phone call came in the chat scripts tied to that tty came to life and did their handshakes. On my then Sun machines it was called /etc/system(s) or maybe /etc/uucp/system(s), with tty, baud rate, and maybe chat script path, but I have no way of ascertaining this. But I recall having one of these in my bedroom and every now and again a call would come in the middle of the night with NNTP updates from my office machines ...

Comment: Just to follow-up (ran out of characters in previous comment), did you try all this with original uucp plumbing? (ie, telephone lines with modems attached?) I remember the tcp enhancement was rather poorly supported across the uucp landscape - only a privileged few had it)